# Caml Query to search a SharePoint List alert if result is empty

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, caml-query

The code below works on success, or if there's a serious error (like the name of the list being wrong) but if the item is not found I receive no error and it does nothing. I just want an alert if the search returns no list item.

```
var EmpNum = $("#searchTxt").val()
EmpNum = $.trim(EmpNum);
if (EmpNum == "")
{
    alert("Please enter an Employee Number!"  );

}
else
{
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');
 var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

 query.set_viewXml(
     "<View>" +
     "<Query>" +
     "<Where>" +
     "<Eq>" +
     "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
     "<Value Type='Text'>" + EmpNum + "</Value>" +
     "</Eq>" +
     "</Where>" +
     "</Query>" +
     "<ViewFields>" +
     "<FieldRef Name='EmployeeLastName' />" +
     "<FieldRef Name='EmployeeFirstName' />" +
     "</ViewFields>" +
     "</View>");

 listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
 clientContext.load(listItems);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Here's the Succeeded:

```
function onQuerySucceeded() {
 var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
 var EmpNum = $("#searchTxt").val()  
 while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
     var itemEmployeeLastName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeLastName');
     var itemEmployeeFirstName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeFirstName');
    PopulateFields(EmpNum, itemEmployeeFirstName, itemEmployeeLastName );
    ;
 }
```

}

Comment: You have to build that into your success function to see if the result set is empty. What does that look like?

Comment: onQuerySucceeded will be hit if the http request is successful, not if it returned what you were expecting. What is your this.onQuerySucceeded function? This is where you need to inspect the output.

Comment: Added. I thought this is where it might be, but didn't know how to inspect the output.

Comment: I got it. I just found the count on listItems and if it is zero it throws an alert.  I'll update the above code. Thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to check the output.

```
function onQuerySucceeded() {

 var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
 var EmpNum = $("#searchTxt").val()  
 while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
     var itemEmployeeLastName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeLastName');
     var itemEmployeeFirstName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeFirstName');
    PopulateFields(EmpNum, itemEmployeeFirstName, itemEmployeeLastName );
    ;
 }
   //Added below check
  if (listItems.get_count() == 0)
 {
    NotFound()
 }
```

}

Comment: Correct, but do it like Eric shows in his answer, a proper if-then-else construct so you are not wasting CPU cycles when there are no items

Answer (score 1):

The onQuerySucceeded function will fire if the http request is successful, it knows nothing about the output. You have to put that into the function. You'd have something like this:

```
function onQuerySucceeded() {
  if (listItems.get_count() == 0) {
    alert("No matching records.");
  }
  else{
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    var EmpNum = $("#searchTxt").val()  
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
      var itemEmployeeLastName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeLastName');
      var itemEmployeeFirstName = currentItem.get_item('EmployeeFirstName');
      PopulateFields(EmpNum, itemEmployeeFirstName, itemEmployeeLastName );
    }
  }
}
```